# Can someone please translate my picture to English! thank you!

Tags: translation

[image: this picture is an image of a motherboard I am having trouble with.]

I am having trouble with this motherboard and I need help translating the text at the bottom to english. thank you!

Comment: left-right,top-bottom:机箱喇叭，重启，硬盘灯，电源灯－绿色，开关 (enter in online dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clockwise,

- 机箱喇叭 - Internal Speaker
- 重启 - Restart
- 开关 - On/Off
- 电源灯 - 绿色 - Power Indicator Light - Green
- 硬盘灯 - Hard Disk Indicator Light